# Xunit Parameterize Selenium By Type

Tags: selenium, serialization, xunit

I have asked several basic questions related to this in the past and got great answers that explained several issues. I think i'm now in a position to ask the correct question now that I'm more aware of how Xunit works!

I am trying to parametrize several tests in C# using visual studio. I need each parameter to be displayed as an individual test that can be ran in isolation if required (I know there is a test collection runner and a separate test runner). The test collection runner is my issue.

I know that Xunit requires the parameters to be serialized in order for them to be picked up by the test collection runner. I also know that it by default can easily serialize basic data types like string, bool, int etc.

I have tried various approaches to do this with mixed results. My issue is trying to parameterize the Selenium type 'By'. I can't seem to be able to serialize this. I've tried to trick Xunit for example by using a dictionary List<string, By> and trying to serialize the  in the dictionary (no luck!)

Here is the cleanest code I have come across that is simple and elegant for what i'm trying to do, but again I can't serialize the 'By' type. I have played around with changing the static property from bool to By and it returns only 1 test for all params, so it's not being serialized

```
public class ParamTest1
{
    static string test3 = "TestXYZ";

    public static TheoryData<int, bool, string, string> DataForTest1 = new TheoryData<int, bool, string, string>
    {
        { 1, true, "First", test3 },
        { 2, false, "Second", test3},
        { 3, true, "Third", test3}
    };

    [Theory(DisplayName = "My First Test"), MemberData(nameof(DataForTest1))]
    public void Test1(int valA, bool valB, string valC, string valD)
    {
        Assert.True(valB);
    }
}
```

Which gives me
[image]

I am aware this particular code isn't invoking the IXunitSerializable

So here is an another working example of what I need but I just can't get it to work with the 'By' Type

```
public class ValidateTestCase : IXunitSerializable
{
    public Guid Coupon { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    public void Serialize(IXunitSerializationInfo info)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(Coupon), Coupon.ToString());
    }

    public void Deserialize(IXunitSerializationInfo info) { }

}

public class Testing
{
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> ValidateTestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new object[] { new ValidateTestCase { Coupon = Guid.Parse("73e4d185-70cf-4ce4-bc3f-187b7a40e167"), IsValid = false } };
            yield return new object[] { new ValidateTestCase { Coupon = Guid.Parse("93b983fb-5b6a-4845-a769-db41900b7df9"), IsValid = false } };
            yield return new object[] { new ValidateTestCase { Coupon = Guid.Parse("99c03283-33cb-4e56-a010-c2bc0758ad27"), IsValid = false } };
            yield return new object[] { new ValidateTestCase { Coupon = Guid.Parse("16a7fe80-3111-44b0-9ebf-c7159bea637d"), IsValid = false } };
            yield return new object[] { new ValidateTestCase { Coupon = Guid.Parse("8b38b4aa-d70f-4ce7-8992-8a60936c5c58"), IsValid = false } };
            yield return new object[] { new ValidateTestCase { Coupon = Guid.Parse("abc60aa0-a33b-4057-8f99-5cdceda35c70"), IsValid = true } };
        }
    }

    [Theory(DisplayName = "CouponService should validate coupons")]
    [MemberData(nameof(ValidateTestCases))]
    public void MyCouponService_Validates(ValidateTestCase vtc)
    {

        Assert.Equal(vtc.IsValid, true);
    }
}
```

And finally for anyone wondering what the 'By' type is I am referring to it's :
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here it is in the debugger so you can see what's going on inside:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I know there's a lot going on in there but if anyone has any ideas or suggestions it would be great!

To summarize, I can't parameterize the Selenium 'data type' By.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcLcn.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9so1.png

Answer (score 0):

Serializing Class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace XUnitTestProject1
{
   
        public class ParameterizedHook
        {
            public By p1 { get; set; }
            public By p2 { get; set; }

            public string assertion { get; set; }
        }

        public class TheoryWrapper<T> : IXunitSerializable
        {
            public TheoryWrapper(string label, T @object)
            {
                Name = label;
                Object = @object;
            }
            public TheoryWrapper()
            {

            }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public T Object { get; set; }

            public void Deserialize(IXunitSerializationInfo info)
            {
                Name = info.GetValue<string>("Label");
                Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(info.GetValue<string>("objValue"));
            }

            public void Serialize(IXunitSerializationInfo info)
            {
                info.AddValue("Label", Name, typeof(string));
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object);
                info.AddValue("objValue", json);
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Name;
            }

        }
    }
```

Working Test

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> ComplexTheoryData
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<object[]>
                {
                    new object[] {0, new TheoryWrapper<ParameterizedHook>("Pass0", new ParameterizedHook { p1 = nav_hold.pip_builder.dash_expand_pip_builder_menu, p2 = nav_hold.pip_builder.dash_project_stages, assertion = "WORK STAGE" })},
                    new object[] {0, new TheoryWrapper<ParameterizedHook>("Pass0", new ParameterizedHook { p1 = nav_hold.pip_builder.dash_expand_pip_builder_menu, p2 = nav_hold.pip_builder.dash_project_stages, assertion = "WORK STAGES" })},
                    //new object[] {0, new TheoryWrapper<ParameterizedHook>("Pass0", new ParameterizedHook { TestData = b.login })},
                    //new object[] {1, new TheoryWrapper<ParameterizedHook>("Pass1", new ParameterizedHook { TestData = b.password })}

                };
            }
        }
        [SkippableTheory]
        [Trait("xUnit", "ForTestRunner")]
        [MemberData(nameof(ComplexTheoryData))]
        public void Test_Navigation(int id, TheoryWrapper<ParameterizedHook> test)
        {
            nav_met.NavMethodTest(test.Object.p1, test.Object.p2);
            By page_title = By.Id("ctl00_lblPageTitle");
            Assert.True(nav_met.VerifyText(page_title, test.Object.assertion));
        }
```